# Binsor: How to use dictionaries whose elements are components in the container

Tags: binsor

Any idea how to configure SortedList whose elements are components register on the container in binsor.

```
Crud:ICrud
 {                
   public SortedList<string, ICrudTransfer> Proxies
   {
   get { return _proxies;}
   set { _proxies = value; }
   }                    
 }
```

I would like to do something like:

```
 component ‘proxy1′, ICrudTransfer
 component ‘proxy2′, ICrudTransfer


 _proxies = SortedList[of string, ICrudTransfer]()
 _proxies['url1']=@proxy1
 _proxies['url2']=@proxy2

 component ’service’, ICrud, Crud:
   Proxies = _proxies
```

But it doesn't work

I would like to use such as properties, arrays or list. That works

```
 component ’service’, ICrud, Crud:
  CrudProxy = @proxy3
  CrudProxies = (@proxy1 , @proxy2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 public class TestClass:ITestClass
    {
        IDictionary<string, IClass1> _dictGen = null;
        IList<IClass1> _listGen = null;

        public IList<IClass1> ListGeneric
        {
            get { return _listGen; }
            set { _listGen = value; }
        }

        public IDictionary<string, IClass1> DictionaryGeneric
        {
            get { return _dictGen; }
            set { _dictGen = value; }
        }
    }

component 'c1', IClass1, Class1
component 'c2', IClass1, Class1

component 'd', ITestClass, TestClass:
  DictionaryGeneric = {key1:@c1,key2:@c2}
  ListGeneric = (@c1,@c2)
```

Without generic (IList or IDictionary) seem not to work.